# Server return status 200 but client doesn't receive it because network connection is broken

Tags: rest, http, post

I have REST service and client (Android app) that send POST request to REST service. On client side there are documents (orders) that need to be synchronized with web server. Synchronization means that client sends POST request to REST service for each order. When REST service receive POST request it writes data to database and sends response with status 200 to client. Client receives 200 and mark that order as synchronized.

**Problem is when connection is broken after a server sent status 200 response but before client received response**. Client doesn't mark order as synchronized. Next time client sends again this order and servers write it again in database so we have same order two times.

What is good practice to deal with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is when connection is broken after a server sent status 200 response but before client received response. Client doesn't mark order as synchronized. Next time client sends again this order and servers write it again in database so we have same order two times.

Welcome to the world of unreliable messaging.

> What is good practice to deal with this kind of problem?

You should review Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging, by [Marc de Graauw](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging) (2010).

The cornerstone of reliable messaging is [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) request handling.  Idempotent *semantics* are described this way

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.

Simply fussing with the request method, however, doesn't get you anything.  First, the *other* semantics in the message may not align with the idempotent request methods, and second the server needs to know how to implement the effect *as intended*.

There are two basic patterns to idempotent request handling.  The simpler of these is `set`, meaning "overwrite the current representation with the one I am providing".

```
// X == 6

server.setX(7)
// X == 7

server.setX(7) <- a second, identical request, but the _effect_ is the same.
// X == 7
```

The alternative is `test and set` (sometimes called `compare and swap`); in this pattern, the request has two parts - a predicate to determine is some condition holds, and the change to apply if the condition does hold.

```
// X == 6

server.testAndSetX(6,7)
// X == 7 

server.testAndSetX(6,7) <- this is a no op, because 7 != 6
// X == 7
```

That's the core idea.

From your description, what you are doing is manipulating a collection of orders.
The same basic idea works there.  If you can calculate a unique identifier from the information in the request, then you can treat your collection like a set/key-value store.

```
// collection.get(Id.of(7)) == Nothing

collection.put(Id.of(7), 7)
// collection.get(Id.of(7)) == Just(7)

collection.put(Id.of(7), 7) <- a second, identical request, but the _effect_ is the same.
// collection.get(Id.of(7)) == Just(7)
```

When that isn't an option, then you need some property of the collection that will change when your edit is made, encoded into the request

```
if (collection.size() == 3) {
   collection.append(7)
}
```

A *generic* way to manage something like this is to consider version numbers -- each time a change is made, the version number is incremented as part of the same transaction

```
// begin transaction
if (resource.version.get() == expectedVersion) {
   resource.version.set(1 + expectedVersion)
   resource.applyChange(request)
}
// end transaction
```

For a real world example, consider JSON Patch, which includes a [test operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6) that can be used as a condition to prevent "concurrent" modification of a document.

What we're describing in all of these `test and set` scenarios is the notion of a [conditional request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)

> Conditional requests are HTTP requests [RFC7231] that include one or more header fields indicating a precondition to be tested before applying the method semantics to the target resource.

What the conditional requests specification gives you is a *generic* way to describe conditions in the meta data of your requests and responses, so that *generic* http components can usefully contribute.

Note well: what this works gets us is not a guarantee that the server will do what the client wants.  Instead, it's a weaker: that the client can safely repeat the request until it receives the acknowledgement from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your documents must have an unique identifier. The semantically correct way would be to use the `If-None-Match` header where you send that identifier.

Then the server checks whether a document with that identifier already exists, and will respond with a `412 Precondition Failed` if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible options would be validation on server side. Order should have some uniqueness parameter: name or id or something else. But this parameter should be send by client also. Then you get this value (e.x. if name is unique and client send it), find this order in database. If order is founded then you don't need to save it into database and should send 409 Conflict response to client. If you din't find such order in database then you save it and send 201 Ok response.

Best practices:

- 201 Ok for POST
- 409 Conflict - if resource already exists

Answer (score 0):

Your requests should be [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html).
From your description, you should be using PUT instead of POST.
Client side generated Ids (guids) and [Upsert](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=upsert) logic server side, help achieve this.
This way you can implement a retry logic client side for failed requests, without introducing multiple records.